# Run coroutine sequentially in python where one routine calls a threadsafe wait()

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, openai-api

I am using Azure's AsyncOpenAI class to send requests asynchronously. I decided to deploy two models so we can switch between them in run time and reduce the number of API calls per model (and reducing the need to wait for the limits to reset).

I have a base client class:

```
class OpenAIClient(Thread):
    def __init__(self, model_config, model_type, logger, time_limit=60, testing=False):
        super(OpenAIClient, self).__init__()
        self.model_config = model_config.copy()
        self.tokens_per_minute_limit = self.model_config.pop("tokens_per_minute_limit")
        self.calls_per_minute_limit = self.model_config.pop("calls_per_minute_limit")
        self.context_window = self.model_config.pop("context_window")
        self.client = AsyncAzureOpenAI(**self.model_config)

        self.time_limit = time_limit
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.time_to_sleep = 0
        self.tokens_so_far = 0
        self.calls_so_far = 0
        self.bit = 0

        self.encoding = tiktoken.encoding_for_model(model_type)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.time_to_sleep)
        # will get reset in self.reset()
        self.start_time = 0

    def track(self, text):
       # tracks number of API calls per minute/tokens sent per minute

    def is_available(self):
       # returns True if has not been previously 
       # used or if num of calls/tokens is under the limit

    def reset(self):
       # resets tokens/api calls thus far

    def sleep(self):
        end_time = time.time()
        # otherwise, wait for the next minute
        self.time_to_sleep = int(self.time_limit - (end_time - self.start_time)) + 1
        self.logger.info(
            f"Waiting for {self.time_to_sleep} seconds to reset GPT-{self.id} limits.\n"
            f"Calls so far: {self.calls_so_far}\n"
            f"Tokens so far: {self.tokens_so_far}"
        )
        # calls self.run() in thread-safe manner
        try:
            self.start()
        except RuntimeError:
            # resets the thread
            super(OpenAIClient, self).__init__()
            self.start()
        self.run()
        self.reset()

    async def get_completion(self, prompt):  # pragma: no cover
        self.logger.info("Calling gpt")
        messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
        response = await self.client.chat.completions.create(
            messages=messages,
            temperature=0,
            model=self.model_config["azure_deployment"],
        )
        return response
```

And then I actually have the caller:

```
class GPTCaller:

    def __init__(self, cfg_list):
        self.client_list = [
            OpenAIClient(
                cfg, model_type=MODEL_TYPE, logger=self.logger, testing=testing_mode
            )
            for cfg in cfg_list
        ]
        self.current_client = self.client_list.pop(0)
        self.current_client.bit = 1

    async def reset(self, text):
        self.current_client.track(text)
        self.logger.info(f"Calls so far: {self.current_client.calls_so_far}")
        self.logger.info(f"Tokens so far: {self.current_client.tokens_so_far}")
        # reset the client if it has been used for more than a minute
        self.current_client.reset()
        if not self.current_client.is_available():
            next_client = self.get_next_client()
            if next_client.is_available():
                # move to the next client if it hasn't been used yet
                self.reset_client()
            else:
                self.current_client.sleep()


    async def get_gpt_response(self, doc_batch, complete_responses, failed_docs):
      
        docs = self.get_prompt() % json.dumps(doc_batch)
        async def get_resp(docs):
            await self.reset(docs)
            resp = await self.current_client.get_completion(docs)
            return resp

        try:
            response = await get_resp(docs)
            if not response:
                failed_docs.extend(doc_batch)
                return 0
            answers = json.loads(response.choices[0].message.content)
            complete_responses.append(pd.DataFrame.from_records(answers))
        except Exception as e:  
            self.logger.warning("Failed to get response from GPT: %s" % str(e))
            failed_docs.extend(doc_batch)
        return 0

    def call_batch(self, df):
        # some logic to turn df into batches of strings
        docs = [logic(grp) for (_, grp) in df.groupby(field)]
        if not docs:
            return None
        self.logger.info("Running GPT calls...")
        await asyncio.gather(*docs)
```

The main issue is guaranteeing that these two lines sequentially within the async calls.

```
await self.reset(docs)
resp = await self.current_client.get_completion(docs)
```

I've tried turning the reset function in my Caller into a regular function and into another async function, doesn't matter.  What ends up happening is that the program hits the reset() and runs through *all* of the reset calls before finally running the gpt calls, defeating the purpose of tracking api calls to gpt and running sleep() when the limits have been reached (as the limits never actually get reached until the gpt call is performed).

I've tried using a Lock() but that turns all of the calls into sequential calls. I've tried using asyncio.Event() but that also doesn't guarantee that reset is called right before calling the API. I've even tried calling gather(reset(), gpt_call()) but there's no guarantee that the execution call order is the same. I could move the wait logic into the gpt call in the client but the client has no idea what the next client would be.  Seems like it would break encapsulation.